# Multiple files ANSI to utf-8 converter

Tags: utf-8, converters

What program can i user to convert **multiple** files from ANSI to UTF-8 ?

Answer (score 1):

On unix, use the `iconv` utility.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a Windows script:

```
var indir = "in";
var outdir = "out";
function ansiToUtf8(fin, fout) {
    var ansi = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream");
    ansi.Open();
    ansi.Charset = "x-ansi";
    ansi.LoadFromFile(fin);
    var utf8 = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream");
    utf8.Open();
    utf8.Charset = "UTF-8";
    utf8.WriteText(ansi.ReadText());
    utf8.SaveToFile(fout, 2 /*adSaveCreateOverWrite*/);
    ansi.Close();
    utf8.Close();
}
var fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var folder = fso.GetFolder(indir);
var fc = new Enumerator(folder.files);
for (; !fc.atEnd(); fc.moveNext()) {
    var file = fc.item();
    ansiToUtf8(indir+"\\"+file.name, outdir+"\\"+file.name);
}
```

This file *ansi2utf8.js* can be run from the command line like so:

```
cscript /Nologo ansi2utf8.js
```

The script expects *in* and *out* directories, but could be modified to do something more flexible.

```
ansi2utf8\ansi2utf8.js
ansi2utf8\in
ansi2utf8\out
ansi2utf8\in\bar.txt
ansi2utf8\in\foo.txt
```